# update the field value(s) with the dynamic values in solr using python

Tags: python, dictionary, solr, tweepy

I have dictionary with updated values and i want to update the field value(s) with the dynamic values in solr using python code.

Bascially i am fetching tweets from tweepy using below logic:

```
outtweets = [[
  dict_1["favorite_count"]=tweet.favorite_count
  dict_1["retweet_count"]=tweet.retweet_count
for idx, tweet in enumerate(all_tweets)]
```

But `favorite_count` and `retweet_count` this fields are dynamic evertime it gets changed.

Below Apache solr Data / schema which already present.

```
{
"favorite_count":0,
"retweet_count":16,
}
```

As fields are dynamic How do i update this specific values in solr ?

Comment: You'll have to explain more - what are you trying to update? The value in Solr? What is the document you're trying to update? What Solr client are you using? How are you currently sending updates or documents to Solr?

Comment: I have updated the question, see above if i am able to explain the scenario !

Comment: You're going to have to attach an id to the document so you know what the numbers are describing. After that, sending the document to Solr by using `pysolr` or another solr client would be done in the regular way (you'll want to add a schema describing the document format in Solr). Updating the document means just sending the same document again with new counts and the same id.

Comment: actually there are so many attributes including id , i have mentioned only two which i need to update

Comment: If you're only going to update those two values for any document that is _already present_, you can use in-place updates (make sure you've enabled `docValues` for those fields): https://solr.apache.org/guide/8_8/updating-parts-of-documents.html#in-place-updates - otherwise, submit the whole document each time you want to update the values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Solr atomic updates to update only the two fields.

```
import pysolr
solr = pysolr.Solr("http://localhost:8983/solr/collectionName")
solr.add({'id':1, 'favorite_count': {'set': 0}, 'retweet_count': {'set': 16}})
solr.commit()
```